# Current disk load

Tags: bash, io, load, iostat

I'm using iostat to get the current disk load each second with `iostat -dx 1` (specially, %util column). However, I'd like to put this in a bash script and control the interval with the `watch` command such as: `watch -n 1 ./script.sh`.

Running the following in `script.sh` won't print a thing:

```
io_load=`iostat -dx 1`
echo $io_load
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `io_load=$(iostat -dx 1)`

Comment: no. does not work. What I'd like it to run `script.sh` with `watch`

Comment: Why not simply use `watch iostat -dx`?

Comment: Try it yourself. And then run `iostat -dx 1`. You will realize that with your suggestion won't update the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The man page of `iostat` says:

```
   The interval parameter specifies the amount of time in seconds between each
   report.  The  first  report  contains  statistics for the time since system
   startup (boot), unless the -y option is used (in this case, this report  is
   omitted).   Each subsequent report contains statistics collected during the
   interval since the previous report.
```

This means the first output of `iostat -dx 1` will be the same as `iostat -dx`, but subsequent outputs are different. - You cannot reproduce this behavior using `watch`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `iostat -dx 1` will not terminate and continuously report values. (The `1` refers to the interval to to the count.)

You probably want something like

```
io_load=$(iostat -dx)
echo "$io_load"
```

Comment: nope. The output never changes. Try it yourself. Running the code you suggest and `iostat -dx 1`

Comment: Try `iostat -dx 1` and `iostat -dx`. The first will not terminate the second will.

Comment: I did try. But running `watch` on the script won't provide an updated output

Comment: It does. Just the output doesn't really change :) You can check it works by using `watch -n 1 "date && iostat -dx"`